# Which Linux program can be used to view the hard disk map?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

On Windows, defragment tools usually show you a preview of your disk: where the file fragment are placed on disk, where is the free space, where is the places that's not movable, etc.

Is there a similar tool for Linux that can show you similar preview or a more detailed map?

I need such tool for some raw disk hacking.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? What kind of raw disk hacking? Do you need a graphical output?

Comment: I look for the something like this: 

http://blog.edgetechcorp.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/DiskDefragment.gif

I don't want to defrag, but want to see that disk map. Probably zoom in if possible.

By raw disk hacking I mean view what's actually stored on the disk sectors, how and where does file placed. Probably modify some bytes.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, you'll probably never have a high level of fragmentation, as the filesystem behaves much better than the Windows counterparts.

For a detailed usage map of your disk, you can use [kdirstat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/) or fsview that comes integrated in konqueror, a web and file browser.